# Acumatica Setting Default Doc Type By Role

Tags: default, doctype, acumatica, role

Is there a way to restrict doc types by user role?

For instance, can I create a customization to allow certain users to only select the "Bill" type from the drop-down in the Bills and Adjustment screen of the Accounts Payable module?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to populate the DocType list based on login user role.

Code example for 'Administrator' role:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.SM;

namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
  { 
    public PXSelect<UsersInRoles,
           Where<UsersInRoles.username, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>,
           And<UsersInRoles.rolename, Equal<Required<UsersInRoles.rolename>>>>> isLoginUserInRole;

    public void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (isLoginUserInRole.Select("Administrator").Count > 0)
      {
          PXDefaultAttribute.SetDefault<APInvoice.docType>(sender, APDocType.Invoice);
        
          PXStringListAttribute.SetList<APInvoice.docType>(sender, 
                                                           null, 
                                                           new string[] { APDocType.Invoice }, 
                                                           new string[] { Messages.Invoice });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When login user is in 'Administrator' role, only 'Bill' is shown in DocType:
[image]